# Postman sendrequest html render

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

if I want to use postman to sendRequest to an html page (as part of a pre-request script), is there any way I can wait for it to fully render before getting the response?
My html page has ajax calls - currently

```
sendRequest(credentials, function(err,res){....})
```

just gets "Loading...." text.
What I want is the html AFTER the ajax calls have completed on the page.
Is this possible?

thanks
Phil